# iMacro Firefox plugin and JQuery AutoCompelete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, imacros

trying to use iMacro Firefox plugin to records a script for site like the following:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

The problem is that when i am trying to play the script after recording it, the JQuery AutoComplete fields doesn't working during the script execution.

Could anyone help me with that?

Best Regards.

Comment: Although I understand your problem, the link in the question isn't working